# Limit collection by enum using lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a collection of objects. One of the properties is "Type" which is an enum. I want to limit the collection by "type" using a lambda and haven't quite figured out how to do it.

Ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to pull out items from the collection based on type? Or do you only want to be able to add things of a certain type to your collection?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
MyEnum type = MyEnum.ValueIWant;
var filtered = items.Where(p => p.Type == type);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use Linq syntax:

```
var filtered = 
    from p in items
    where p.Type == MyEnum.ValueIWant
    select p;
```

This will compile to exactly the same code as @Jason's suggestion.